# Where is the formal specification for java.lang?

Tags: java, specifications

There are JLS (and JVMS) defining the "core" java. There are also a lot of JSRs extending its functionality. But is there a specifications for Java's standard library like `java.lang`?

The closest I found is [Java™ Platform, Standard Edition 8 API Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/), but it feels more like documentation rather than specification. Is this doc the official spec for java standard library APIs? Do vendors other than oracle (like AdoptOpenJdk, etc) read this doc-like spec and implement their version of JRE? Or there is another more "formal/official" spec?

Comment: Well, at least `Object`, `String`, and the primitive wrapper types are extensively discussed in the JLS, and are required.

Comment: The JLS is the only specification of the language and its core components. Any Java implementation must adhere to it. If something is not covered in the JLS, then it is not mandatory to be part of a valid Java implementation. Note that you can take the Javadoc of the classes themselves as some kind of specification as well, as Java maintains backwards compatibility. So if a class says *"iteration order is insertion order"* then you can rely on that, it will not change in future releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the Java Doc comments define the official API specification, as per [their statement](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html):

> Our documentation comments define the official Java Platform API Specification

There is no other "more official" documentation for the Java API. They elaborate more on using Java Docs as specification in the linked article:

> There are commonly two different ways to write doc comments -- as API specifications, or as programming guide documentation. These two targets are described in the following sections. A staff with generous resources can afford to blend both into the same documentation (properly "chunked"); however, **our priorities dictate that we give prime focus to writing API specifications in doc comments**. This is why developers often need to turn to other documents, such as Java SE Technical Documentation and The Java Tutorials for programming guides